# Remove extra blank lines before lists when exporting to html

Tags: org-export

When exporting org files to html, the orgmode exporter adds a `<br>` blank line before `org-ul` lists. I'd like to get rid of these extra blank lines (which are not visually "standard", in french documents at least).

I’ve tried to tweak the css (readtheorg.css here) with a negative `margin-top` for `org-ul`. Not only this solution is inelegant, but it fails where a list directly follows a headline (headline is then overlapped).

Any stronger workaround ? Within a org-export hook ? (beyond my skills)